# Using Distinct() for filtering duplicated records in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, asqueryable

I have some duplicated email records. I also need to return `IQueryable` type.

I tried `Distinct()` but I did not work for me because I want to return `IQueryable` Type. I got an error that cannot implicitly convert type system collections generic list to `System.Linq.IQueryable` (Are you missing a cast):

```
public IQueryable<acadVParent> GetEmailReceiptsId()
{
   return AsQueryable().Where(o => (o.email != null && o.email != ""));
}
```

So this has duplicated emails in the collection. I would want to exclude the object record that has duplicated email records.

Comment: Where is the `AsQueryable` static you are using defined?

Comment: Are you missing something before the `AsQueryable`?

Comment: Hi Shwan, welcome to SO. Is `AsQueryable` some method you created? If so, where is the source? Otherwise, I don't think the sample code you provided would compile. If you are trying to reference the `IQueryable` extension method from Linq, then it should be called upon some variable of type `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @shwan please write a message to me it is very important (maythamfahmi@itbackyard.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just group by email and take the first one in each group (remove duplicates), and at the end convert it to Queryable (here I assume the `List` or `Array`, ... name is list):

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.email).Select(g => g.First()).AsQueryable();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked and it saved me too much work around solution.